# Carrying forward commission database design

Tags: database-design, user-experience

I have a table containing a summary of the commission generated on a monthly basis. Commission can only be paid out when it is $50 and above.

In my example, the commission is insufficient and there is a need to wait for the following month to see whether the combined commission is sufficient for a payout. How do I handle this scenario? I am using a MySQL database.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI5q7.png]

Comment: How do you determine who gets a payout?  Transaction ID?